# How get height of divs element in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

how i get height of all divs in array?

```
let controlLabels = document.querySelectorAll(".form-group > .control-label");
let arrayControlLabels = Array.from(controlLabels);
for (let i = 0; i < arrayControlLabels.length; i++) {
  let elementHeight = arrayControlLabels[i].clientHeight;
  console.log(elementHeight);
}
```

I need compare height in if like a

```
    if (elementHeight > 40) {
        do something
    } else {
        continue in for loop
    }
```

When i do this, if write to console only the bigger that 40 but no other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the spread operator `...` with the node collection to get an actual array and `forEach()` instead of a `for` loop.

Then check for the `offsetHeight` property of the *nth* label

```
let labelsArray = [...document.querySelectorAll(".form-group > .control-label")];
labelsArray.forEach((label) => {
   if (label.offsetHeight > 40) {
      // do something
   }
});
```

if you have instead to create an array only with labels whose height is `> 40px` then you can use `Array.prototype.filter()`, e.g.

```
let onlyLabelsGT40 = labelsArray.filter((label) => {
   return label.offsetHeight > 40
});
```

Comment: Maybe `array#filter`?

Comment: Not sure from the question if the array needs to contain all the labels or just only labels with height > 40.

Comment: Thanks you so much, you save my day - @Fabrizio Calderan

Answer (score 0):

You can use the property `height` from the result of [`Element.getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect):

```js
let controlLabels = document.querySelectorAll(".form-group > .control-label");
let arrayControlLabels = Array.from(controlLabels);
for (let i = 0; i < arrayControlLabels.length; i++) {
  let elementHeight = arrayControlLabels[i].getBoundingClientRect().height;
  if(elementHeight > 40) {
    // do something here
  }
}
```

The only question here is what your "40" is. If you mean pixels, then this solution will work when the zoom level on the user's browser is the default (100%).